# Java SWT WYSIWYG HTML Editor

Tags: java, html, editor, swt, wysiwyg

I search for a WYSIWYG HTML Editor. I will use it in an existing project to generate HTML code. So the user should insert and style the code in the editor. If the user save or push a button I will get the HTML code and save it in a Database.

Has anybody an idea for a widget with these features?

Comment: seamonkey?  not exactly a 'widget'..

Comment: *"WYSIWYG HTML Editor"*  No such thing.  You want WYSIWYG, go PDF.  HTML was designed to be WUGIWUS (what user gets is what user wants).  If that means changing the specified font face and size, the background and foreground color and swapping all images for the `alt` text, so be it.  Please don't include 'sigs' in questions - it is noise.

Comment: I used TinyMCE integrated into an Eclipse RCP app, it was years ago, I don't know its current status but you can take a look at that

Answer (score 1):

The [Mylyn Docs](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=mylyn.docs) project has a WYSIWYG editor, for an example usage see the attachment of [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319018)

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux there're two editors:

- [GWrite](https://code.google.com/p/gwrite/): GTK+/Webkit-based
- KompoZer: Mozilla geco-based

Unfortunately, both of them are not mature enough.

Comment: Why do you recommend applications that are not mature enough? What are the pros/cons for each of them? Why should they be used?

Answer (score 0):

If JavaFX is an option: it provides a HTML editor, which can be embedded into SWT applications:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/web/package-summary.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse EPF](https://www.eclipse.org/epf/) project provides a RichtText Editor:

**EPF Richtext Feature** - can be downloaded at the bottom:
https://www.eclipse.org/epf/downloads/tool/epf1.5.0_downloads.php
API
https://www.eclipse.org/epf/composer_javadoc/org/eclipse/epf/richtext/package-summary.html

But seems like this requires a complete Eclipse RCP application not only SWT, but maybe an option.